# Remove the big play button appears on <video> tag in firefox mobile

Tags: button, firefox, mobile, mozilla, playback

I've been struggeling with this one for a long time and haven't found a solution yet.

I have a preloader on my friend's website which I built (he insist of keeping it)
the preloader is applied with the video tag like so:

```
<video muted autoplay loop playsinline preload frameborder="0" width="100" height="100">
     <source src="/media/preloader.webm#t=0.25" type="video/webm">
     <source src="/media/preloader.mp4#t=0.25" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="/media/preloader.mov#t=0.25" type="video/quicktime">
</video>
```

on all browser that's working great, but on firefox mobile before video is playing I see this play button(for half a second):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRpal.png

What can I do to remove this annoying button for good?